# Why terminal doesn't show the return value in python? Here is my code and output

Tags: python

Input

```
def dis():
        print ("I will forget you oneday.")
        return 2
# I make a return value in code.
dis()
```

Output

```
I will forget you oneday.
```

There is only a print line and no return value.
Can someone help me know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `print(dis())`?

Comment: Why should the return value be printed? There's no code to actually do that.

Comment: A function that returns something will need `print` statement to output the return values.

Comment: Thank you all. I was confusing return value will display if I called the function.